# error when i am trying to run android app

Tags: android-manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><<manifest >  

<xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
package="com.example.mahdi.lebtaxi"  

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application android:allowBackup="true"  
             android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"   
             tools:replace="android:icon"  
             android:label="@string/app_name"  
             android:supportsRtl="true"  
           android:theme="@style/AppTheme">  

 <activity  android:name=".Profile"  
            android:label="@string/title_activity_profile"  
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>  

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />  

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />  

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />  


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />  

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />  

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" />

<activity android:name=".Booking" />  

<activity android:name=".Cars" />  

<activity android:name=".Payments" />  

<activity android:name=".Login" />  

<activity android:name=".SignUp" />  

<activity android:name=".Splash">  

<intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest doesn't seem to have an Activity.

You can modify the manifest using below format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="in.example.app">

//permissions
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```